# mechanism to collect crashing and errors [android]

Tags: android, debugging, crash-reports

Now we start testing of our application. It is not in Market yet, so I try to find usefull mechanism to collect statistic about application crashes, exceptions and memeory usage.
How you decide this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) library Or implements your own crash report.